# How to retrieve the id of the checked checkbox in android

Tags: android, checkbox

```
   String s;
   CheckBox cb[]= new CheckBox[n];
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {   
      // CheckBox
      String label = a[i];
      cb[i]=new CheckBox(this);
      cb[i].setText(label);
      cb[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#006400"));
      cb[i].setId(i);
   }

  if(cb[i].isChecked()) {
      s+=i+",";
  }
```

Tried using this in the loop itself
but no change in the value of s
Cannot implement listener without making s a final variable

Comment: your code is incomplete and badly indented. Can you update it to ease our reading ?

Comment: I did not feel the whole chunk of code was required only gave the ones that matter

Answer (score 0):

try using something like below.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
     ---
      ----
     ----


if(cb[i].isChecked())
  {
       s.append(i+",");
    }
```

later you can convert this to String byt `S.toString()` method;

Comment: Well its almost the same job that my code is doing, what i cant understand is when to use isChecked() does it work just after the loop creating the buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list and declare the string outside your onCreate method :

```
private String s;

public void onCreate... {
    final List<Integer> map = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    CheckBox[] ch = ...;
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++) {
    ch[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
                map.add(buttonView.getId());
            } else {
                map.remove(buttonView.getId());
            }
            s = "";
            for (Integer i : map) {
                s += i+",";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I also tried this approach, the only problem is that from this i could get the id or parameter of the button itself. But what i want to do is get the id and then append name[id] in a string, where name is a string array which i cannot declare final. The ide gives me error that non final variable cannot be accessed in ........